Keeping both sides of a bidirectional one-to-many reference consistent in java
I've done a lot of googling about this without much success, every time I look how people update bidirectional relations, it looks something like this:
class Book {
  @ManyToOne
  private Bookshelf bookshelf;

  public void setBookshelf(Bookshelf newBookshelf) {
    this.bookshelf = newBookshelf;
  }
}

class Bookshelf {
  @OneToMany
  private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addBookshelf(Book book) {
    books.add(book);
    book.setBookshelf(book);
  }
}

This will work fine for updating entity relations, but in the actual class references, isn't it very easy to create an inconsistency, for example if a user calls setBookshelf without every calling addBookshelf, or if a user calls addBookshelf on a Book that is already in another Bookshelf
In my own project I've come up with something like this but it seems painfully complicated, I'm wondering how people do this, is the answer just "Don't call setBookshelf"? My initial intuition was to make setBookshelf package-private, but unfortunately in my actual code the two classes are in seperate packages
    public void setAuthor(WebsiteUser newAuthor) {
        // Check for no change needed
        if (this.author != null && this.author.equals(newAuthor)) {
            return;
        }

        // Remove from old author, if necessary
        if (this.author != null) {
            this.author.removeProductCollection(this);
        }

        this.author = newAuthor;

        // Check for null
        if (this.author == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (! this.author.getProductCollections().contains(this)) {
            this.author.addProductCollection(this);
        }
    }

    public void addProductCollection(ProductCollection newProductCollection) {
        // Check for no change needed
        if (newProductCollection == null || productCollections.contains(newProductCollection)) {
            return;
        }

        productCollections.add(newProductCollection);

        if (newProductCollection.getAuthor().isPresent() && ! newProductCollection.getAuthor().get().equals(this)) {
            newProductCollection.setAuthor(this);
        }
    }


You can efficiently manage bidirectional relationships by using @JoinColumn and the mappedBy attribute.
To put it simply, the @JoinColumn annotation is used to map a foreign key, while the mappedBy attribute is used to define the owner of the relationship.
In many-to-one and one-to-many relationships, the "many" side usually holds the foreign key. Therefore, it becomes the owner of the relationship.
Let me explain with some code examples.
Book
class Book {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOKK_SHELF_ID")
    private Bookshelf bookshelf;

    public void setBookshelf(Bookshelf newBookshelf) {
        this.bookshelf = newBookshelf;
    }
}

BookShelf
class Bookshelf {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookshelf")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}

Using mappedBy, the Bookshelf field in the Book class is set as the owner of the relationship. Therefore, you can now manage the foreign key using the Book class's Bookshelf field.
@Service
public class BookService {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void setBookshelf(Long bookId, Bookshelf bookshelf) {
        Book book = bookRepository.findById(bookId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid book Id:" + bookId));
        book.setBookshelf(bookshelf);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveBookWithBookshelf(Book book, Bookshelf bookshelf) {
        book.setBookshelf(bookshelf);

        bookRepository.save(book);
    }
}

Reference Document

What does relationship owner means in bidirectional relationship?
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/jpa-determining-the-owning-side-of-a-relationship.html

